# Type namespace is not declared or is not a simple type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I am trying to use a type that is defined in one schema file and use it in another. I believe the format is correct but I keep receiving the same error message upon validation.

Main Schema File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:deliverableNamespace" xmlns:mstns="urn:deliverableNamespace" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:deliverableNamespace">
<xs:include schemaLocation="ManageDeliverableLookup.xsd" />
 <xs:element name="GEMS">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="header">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="token" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="timestamp" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="system">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="SystemIdLkup" use="required"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Second Schema File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema id="ManageDeliverableLookup" targetNamespace="urn:deliverableNamespace" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="urn:deliverableNamespace" xmlns:mstns="urn:deliverableNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:simpleType name="SystemIdLkup">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
      <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="16"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="18"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="56"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="150"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="151"/>
    </xs:restriction>

  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your XSDs per se.  Please post your XML and whether you wish to change the XSDs or the XML to get the XML to be valid.  Thanks.

Comment: And also, can you post the "same error message upon validation" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Casual glance yielded this, may not solve your issue but might help get you closer: Your targetnamespace is the same value in both XSDs. They should be distinct as the target namespace represents the elements declared in the current document. You have two documents  therefore you need two targetnamespaces.